# File written through mapped drive letter giving 404 in iis 10

Tags: iis

I have a server with iis 10.  I have a process on another server that maps a drive to a folder under a website.  I am writing an image to that folder and then sending a payload to another api server to pull that file.  Sometimes it returns a 404 and I can see it in my logs as well.  If go there, that file exists and can be accessed through a browser.  The file is definitely there when I call the api to have the file pulled.  Does anyone know if there is some reason for this and more importantly, a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Mapped drives are not supported by IIS https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257174/using-mapped-drives-with-iis

Comment: That article is actually not relevant because that is talking about housing data on a remote location using a mapped drive.  In my situation, the folder with the data is on the webserver and I am using a drive mapped from another server to write to that folder on the webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure this was the issue, but pretty sure it was, but the server cpu was maxed out at times because of hung IIS processes and once those were cleared and we resolved that, this issue was resolved as well.